# Prevent JavaFX Tooltip from focusing background stage

Tags: javafx

In an application that has several stages, the user can make another stage appear with a click which I'll refer to as "the stage of interest". "The stage of interest" appears in front of the other ones which is good

The problem is that the stages behind "the stage of interest" have Tooltips and if a Tooltip is shown then the stage it belongs to jumps in front

I am aware of similar looking questions like this: [displaying a tooltip in javafx brings its stage into the foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416738/displaying-a-tooltip-in-javafx-brings-its-stage-into-the-foreground)

However the difference is that I want the background Tooltips to continue to work but just not steal focus

Comment: Maybe catch it on a listener `Tooltip.setOnShowing()` to do something like `Stage.requestFocus()`?

Comment: @trilogy, Neither `Tooltip.setOnShowing(event -> { Stage.requestFocus(); });` nor `Tooltip.setOnShowing(event -> { Platform.runLater(() -> { Stage.requestFocus(); }); });` appear to work unfortunately

Comment: Did you consume as well?

Comment: @trilogy, `event.consume();` followed by `Platform.runLater(() -> Stage.requestFocus() );` is also a no-go (also a no-go without `Platform.runLater`)

Comment: just a note: the title is mis-leading - the focused window isn't changed on hovering, just its z-order, so requesting focus has no effect. That said: a) there isn't much api to configure z-order, just toFront/toBack b) whatever trick we apply, we must wait until the default changes are complete - so register a listener to the tooltip's shownProperty and force the focused window to front again.

Comment: @kleopatra `setOnShown` or `setOnShowing`?

Comment: @trilogy onShown (in onShowing the internal state is not yet updated completely)

Comment: @kleopatra, What you suggested does work but the example in my question was a simplification of the real application. In reality there are many kinds of windows that could be in front. It would be much better to just disable the z-order change of the Tooltip

Comment: not possible afsik